# How do I specify "per call" jQuery AJAX options on a :remote form_tag?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple form (that's enabled using ujs to make an ajax call with jQuery). I would like to specify the DataType of the response (by default it doesn't seem to pay much attention to "text", and I'm getting a jQuery.ajaxError.

How/where do I specify the DataType? (I don't want to specify it for all calls, just a particular one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh

... form_tag ... :'data-type' => 'text' ...

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

I'm sure jQuery has this documented "somewhere", but I was unable to find it at this time. (re: jQuery and html5 data-* attributes)

Answer (score 0):

dataType is declared in the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myurl.com/script.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'a=1&b=2',
    success: function(){
        alert('Great Success!')
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('Bummer.')
    }
});
```

Or whatever your call looks like since you didn't bother to post it...  >:(

In your script, make sure you `echo json_encode();` whatever data it is you're working with.

Comment: I'd post it if I knew where to find it. This is how the form is generated:
<%= form_tag 'ajax', :remote => true, :'data-update-target' => 'update-container' do %>